# What's the difference between segregate and separate as verb?

Tags: differences

1 **segregate somebody (from somebody)** to separate people of different races, religions, or sexes and treat them in a different way

a culture in which women are segregated from men

Whites and blacks were segregated into different parts of town.

a racially segregated community

a segregated school (= one for students of one race or religion only)

opposite integrate

2 **segregate something (from something)** to keep one thing separate from another

In all our restaurants, smoking and non-smoking areas are segregated from each other.

Answer (score 7):

All [segregation](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20segregate) is separation, but of a particular kind, that of dividing some group into different segments based on some criterion, so a hospital administrator would say

> We **segregate** those with communicable diseases from the rest of the patient population.

This reflects the word's origin from the Latin *grex* meaning flock.  *Separate* would work as well.

*Separate* means generally to divide, so a geographer would say

> The Mississippi River **separates** the United States into east and west.

*Segregates* would be inapt here.

Comment: In AusE the "usual" term would be "isolate those with communicable diseases ...", even though segregation has never had the same level of political overtones as it has/had in the US or South Africa.

Answer (score 2):

Originally, the difference was that *separate* meant to take two or more classes of things or people and put them in different places. But *segregate* meant to take one of these classes and isolate it from all the others.

This was the meaning even before racial segregation was instituted (so you can see that the very word *segregation* implied that the two races were not treated equally).

From Webster's original 1828 dictionary:

> **segregate**: to separate from others; to set apart.
>
> **separate**: To disunite; to divide; to sever; to part, in almost any manner, either things naturally or casually joined.

Answer (score 0):

*In all our restaurants, smoking and non-smoking areas are segregated from each other.*

I can't agree this is standard usage at all, for a number of reasons:

- Firstly (and obviously) the policy statement is tautologous (if there are smoking and non-smoking areas then they would be separate, you would expect)
- So you would simply say: "In all our restaurants there are smoking and non-smoking sections."
- Segregate / segregated / segregation are very loaded words (with a lot of political baggage), and would not (or should not) be used in the context of a restaurant policy about smoking

So for the avoidance of unwanted political overtones, "separate" is usually the safer word to use for putting or keeping two people (or two objects) apart - "segregate" should be used very cautiously in quite specific ways.  And "integrate" is the antonym of "segregate" only in very specific cases as well.

Comment: "would not (or should not) be used in the context of a restaurant policy" Except for sport.